# Create a input textbox without using <input type="text">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I want to create a input textbox that does not require a `<input type="text">` form element. The user can still type text into this textbox and the value can still be retrieved using Javascript/jQuery. The reason for doing this is because this textbox will be in a form that upon submit, all form input values will be sent to the server side for processing, and there is this textbox that I dont want its values to be automatically send to server side.

**Problem:** What is the best way to create such a textbox without relying on HTML form elements `input`?

Comment: Create the input in another form.

Comment: Remove the borders and outline of the text input and put it in a div as an only child.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just don't give the `<input type="text">` tag a `name` attribute and it won't submit. Here is an example:

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" value="you will not see this submitted" />
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to OPs problem. Creating a textbox by not using an input tag is silly.

Answer (score 8):

You could use a contenteditable div, too.

From the MDN:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div contenteditable="true">
      This text can be edited by the user.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Comment: +1 This is what I would have said too, but be aware that this doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: It works on all major desktop browsers. Mobile support is lacking, though.

Answer (score 1):

if you create dynamic `<input type="text">` by jQuery - it WILL post back its values.

What do you care if its values are posted back ? just dont do anything with them in the server side.

or  ,

before submit - change the type from input to label. ( + save values)

or  ,

**if youll add the input OUTSIDE  the FORM element - it wont submit.**

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `textarea` instead of `input`. then apply stlying with css. also you can use your input tag, just keep it outside the `<form></form>` then it won't be send over to the server.

Answer (score 1):

just create the input, and don't give it a `name` or `id`.

Comment: You can still give it an `id` attribute. It will only get submitted if it has a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#form").bind('submit', function() {
  $(this).children('input[name=excludethisfield]').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

I know this isn't specifically what you asked but might be the easiest way.

Comment: I don't see what this accomplishes. Users don't edit form input fields after they hit the submit button anyway.

Comment: @Asaph the disabled attribute will cause it to not post.